# query for calculating time spent in office

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table with columns: Lastname, date and time of enter to office, date and time of exit

[image]

I have to write the query, that returns quantity of hours that employer spent at the office per week, for example

[image]

I have no idea how to do it, Please help.

Comment: Lookup for `DATEPART` & `DATEDIFF`

Comment: To get week number use this SELECT DATEPART( wk, @Dt)
Then create query with week number and do aggregation.

Comment: For the hours, you can do sum(datediff, etc.  Before you finish it, make sure you know how to deal with partial hours.   For the week starting and ending part, a calendar table comes in handy for that sort of thing.  That enables you to specify whether weeks start on Sunday or Monday, or whatever your business specifies.

Comment: Is it possible that enter and exit belongs to two different weeks?

Comment: @McNets, that`s not possible for simplification the task

Comment: @Prdp, thanks for attention, i will read information about it.

Comment: @DanBracuk, thanks for attention and advice

Answer (score 0):

**Test Data**

```
Declare @T TABLE (EmpID INT , Enter DATETIME , [Exit] DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
 (1 , '2017-01-22 09:26:00.000' , '2017-01-22 15:25:00.000')
,(1 , '2017-01-21 10:15:00.000' , '2017-01-21 12:00:00.000')
,(1 , '2017-01-20 09:05:00.000' , '2017-01-20 13:05:00.000')
,(1 , '2017-01-21 10:15:00.000' , '2017-01-21 12:00:00.000')
,(2 , '2017-01-22 09:26:00.000' , '2017-01-22 15:26:00.000')
,(2 , '2017-01-21 10:15:00.000' , '2017-01-21 12:30:00.000')
,(2 , '2017-01-20 09:05:00.000' , '2017-01-20 13:05:00.000')
```

**Query**

```
Select EmpID
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10) ,DATEADD(DAY, -  (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Enter)-1), Enter) , 104) [WeekStart]
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10) ,DATEADD(DAY, 7- (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Enter)), Enter)   , 104)   [WeekEnd]
    , CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(minute,Enter, [Exit])) / 60.00 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) [Hours Worked]

FROM @T 
GROUP BY EmpID
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10) ,DATEADD(DAY, -  (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Enter)-1), Enter) , 104) 
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10) ,DATEADD(DAY, 7- (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Enter)), Enter)   , 104)
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═══════╦════════════╦════════════╦══════════════╗
║ EmpID ║ WeekStart  ║  WeekEnd   ║ Hours Worked ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬════════════╬══════════════╣
║     1 ║ 15.01.2017 ║ 21.01.2017 ║         7.50 ║
║     1 ║ 22.01.2017 ║ 28.01.2017 ║         5.98 ║
║     2 ║ 15.01.2017 ║ 21.01.2017 ║         6.25 ║
║     2 ║ 22.01.2017 ║ 28.01.2017 ║         6.00 ║
╚═══════╩════════════╩════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Comment: you saved me, thank you very much. I wish you success in everything